# Подскажите библиотеку или движек для работы с 3D графикой при создании Android приложения

Tags: java, android, 3d, android-library

В приложение требуется добавить один 3D элемент, но движек Uniti не хочется использовать для такой простой задачи. Есть ли какие то хорошие альтернативы? Пишу для Android на Java, использую Android Studio.

Comment: погуглите - создание 3D движка...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте libgdx, это java библиотека. Она создана для создания игр с использованием java. Написанное приложение с помощью, буквально 10 (а может и меньше) строк кода может работать и на android, desktop, ios, html5. Но она ориентирована для игр и я не знаю подойдет ли она для вашего приложения.